# Master Page-ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

when I tried to create Web Form using Master page I got the HttpException:

```
   HttpException (0x80004005): Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.]
```

The Master Page:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="adminNav.master.cs" Inherits="Site.AdminPages.adminNav" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Admin Page</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Site/Scripts/CSS/AdminPage.css" />
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="bs-example">
    <form runat="server">
        <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <asp:LinkButton class="navbar-brand" Style="color: white" ID="AdminHomePage" runat="server" href="/Site/AdminPages/AdminPage.aspx">Home</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/AdminPages/Users.aspx")%>">Users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/AdminPages/Profile.aspx")%>">Profile</a></li>                                                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                <asp:Label ID="emailDeatilsLabel" runat="server" Style="color: white"></asp:Label>
                                <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LogOutLabel" runat="server" href="/Site/UserPages/LogOut.aspx">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </form>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the code of Profile.aspx ( what I tried to run and got the exception ):

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminPages/adminNav.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="Site.AdminPages.Profile" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="explainText">
            First name:
        <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="ProfilefirstNameTextBox" class="form-control" runat="server" Width="250px" ForeColor="Black" placeholder="First Name" required="true" OnTextChanged="ProfilefirstNameTextBox_TextChanged" />
    </body>    
    </html>
```

I tried also to write in Profile.aspx code only the elements (without ...) code but its still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page

Visual Studio is telling you do do the following;

Wrap your mark up with the placeholder tags like this

```
<asp:Content Id="ContentI" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

 <p class="explainText">
        First name:
    <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="ProfilefirstNameTextBox" class="form-control" runat="server" Width="250px" ForeColor="Black" placeholder="First Name" required="true" OnTextChanged="ProfilefirstNameTextBox_TextChanged" />

</asp:Content>
```

You do not need to  put the html  and body tags as they are injected from the master page.That is how master and child pages work.